# IPC between .NET and Java client applications

Tags: c#, java, .net, ipc

I must get two different client application talk without any kind of broker or server.
What is the best method for IPC beween two process, Java and .NET?

It must able to be work in multi-user termainl server, so no socket please.
I wish that it is lightweight and simple, something plug and run, so no RMI/WS please.

I'm now thinking about JNI to access Mutex and Named pipes, am I going to a right direction?

Any ideas welcome!

Thanks Dennis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access WinAPI through JNI(Java) and PInvoke(C#). 
Use following WinAPI functions:
CreateEvent
SetEvent
WaitForSingleObject
CreateMutex
ReleaseMutex
CreateFileMapping (for share memory)
MapViewOfFile
UnmapViewOfFile

Answer (score 7):

I am author of [jni4net](http://jni4net.sf.net/), open source intraprocess bridge between JVM and CLR. It's build on top of JNI and PInvoke. No C/C++ code needed. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).

> Protocol Buffers are a way of encoding structured data in an efficient yet extensible format. Google uses Protocol Buffers for almost all of its internal RPC protocols and file formats.

Comment: ProtoBuf doesn't support .NET on its own. You'd also need https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/