# Passing event from C# application to Java application

Tags: c#, java, events, filesystemwatcher

I have a Java application that launches a small C# application on the client machine.

I need a simple solution for passing events between the C# and the Java applications.

To handle the opposite direction (Java->C#) I was using FileSystemWatcher, which listens to folder change events.
The Java application writes an empty file to a shared folder, and the C# app handles these events according to the (empty) file name (and then removes it from the "queue").
Could not find a Java equivalent to FileSystemWatcher to solve the problem of passing events from C# to Java.

Any creative idea ? (reminder: this is just a Java application so I have no Apache server or something like that).

Thanks

Comment: you are passing events via the file system?

Comment: It is certainly not necessary to have Apache installed in order to have a web server. You can have a small web server integrated into your app. But because you are communicating with an app on the local machine, there are no firewall issues to worry about, so it's not essential to communicate over port 80, or use HTTP - you can use any kind of TCP/IP sockets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice simple writeup written in 2010

[Use Named Pipes to Communicate Between Java and .Net Processes](http://v01ver-howto.blogspot.com/2010/04/howto-use-named-pipes-to-communicate.html)

Comment: Looks like an interesting solution, thanks. However, before testing it I was wondering: it uses .Net as the server and Java as the client, while I would need the other way around (.Net sends events to Java). Would is still work for me ?

Comment: named pipes aren't anything to do with servers, they are essentially virtual files. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe

Comment: @Ranch, it should still work the same with a bit of code alterations. @Gordon, I think @Ranch is referring more to the roles that each play when mentioning server/client. Based on the context from his question all this takes place on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/

That's probably an option for you.

This seems like a duplicate of

[IPC between .NET and Java client applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317327/ipc-between-net-and-java-client-applications)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple JMS server like ActiveMQ to pass messages back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

basically you need inter process communication. There are many way for it.

- Socket
- Named Pipes
- Any distributed queue like RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, e.t.c.
- Named Mutex

http://www.ikvm.net/

e.t.c.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible ways but they generally fall into two categories:

java<->c# interop (like http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) 
or 
some form of standardized communication like webservices (they don't require a "server" to work) such as WCF in C# and Metro on the java side.

BTW: You really shouldn't be using the file system to pass events.

Comment: I had a feeling using the file system wouldn't be the perfect solution, but it is working fine and stable enough. Any other reason I shouldn't be using it ?

Comment: Lets see:
1. What happens if the listening side crashes - how would the other side know about it? it would simply keep writing empty files and may eventually crash.
2. There is no confirmation that a message was received which is important for some types of communication.
3. This can be easily interfered with - other applications don't expect you to write data to some folder. The user could try to open one of the files which will prevent the listener from erasing it.
(out of chars - more in next message)

Comment: 4. writing and erasing from the file system takes time, this puts a very hard constraint on the time it takes to send/receive messages.
5. there's a hard constraint on the length of a message (max file name length).
I am sure others can come up with plenty of other reasons, but mainly: there are standard, well documented, comprehensive , working solutions to this problem. There's no need to reinvent the wheel. you're likely to re-solve all the problems that were already solved by someone else.